# Filling NaN values with those contained in a different DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The problem looks like this:

## Problem

I have a dataframe `left` with a 2-level multiindex, representing events `tpc` occurring at point `onset` in the time region `mc`. Every event occurs in a layer defined by `(staff, voice)`:

```
            mc onset  staff  voice  tpc  dynamics  chords
section ix                                               
0       0    0     0      2      1    0       NaN     NaN
        1    0     0      2      1    0       NaN     NaN
        2    0     0      1      1    0       NaN     NaN
        3    0     0      1      1    4       NaN     NaN
        4    0     0      1      1    1       NaN     NaN
        5    0     0      1      1    0       NaN     NaN
        6    0   3/4      2      2    1       NaN     NaN
        7    0   3/4      2      1    1       NaN     NaN
```

Then, there is the dataframe `right` with other events `('dynamic', 'chords')`, which need to be filled into `left`:

```
   mc onset  staff  voice dynamics chords
0   0     0      1      1        f    NaN
1   0     0      1      1      NaN      I
2   0   1/2      2      1        p    NaN
3   0   3/4      1      1      NaN     I6
4   0   3/4      2      1      NaN    I64
```

#### The rules for filling are as follows:

1. All events from `right` need to appear in `left`
2. If they co-occur with `left` events in the same layer, fill in the respective column of `left` for those events (i.e., join on `['mc', 'onset', 'staff', 'voice']`; e.g. rows 0, 1, 4)
3. Else if they co-occur with `left` events in the same `staff`, fill in the respective column of `left` for those events (i.e., join on `['mc', 'onset', 'staff']`; e.g. row 4)
4. Else if they co-occur with `left` events in some other layer, fill in the respective column of `left` for those events (i.e., join on `['mc', 'onset']`, e.g. row 3)
5. Else if they don't co-occur with `left` events, throw a warning and keep them for further treatment (e.g. row 2)
6. If two events of the same type within `right` occur simultaneously, throw a warning and concatenate values (e.g. rows 3 & 4)

### Expected result

```
     mc onset  staff  voice  tpc dynamics chords
0 0   0     0      2      1    0      NaN    NaN
  1   0     0      2      1    0      NaN    NaN
  2   0     0      1      1    0      f        I
  3   0     0      1      1    4      f        I
  4   0     0      1      1    1      f        I
  5   0     0      1      1    0      f        I
  6   0   3/4      2      2    1      NaN     I6
  7   0   3/4      2      1    1      NaN  I6I64
WARNING: These events could not be attached:
   mc onset  staff  voice dynamics chords
2   0   1/2      2      1        p    NaN
WARNING: These events are simultaneous:
   mc onset  staff  voice dynamics chords
3   0   3/4      1      1      NaN     I6
4   0   3/4      2      1      NaN    I64
```

## Attempt 1

Since I would like to avoid an approach where I iterate through `right`, I tried the following:

```
left_features = ['mc', 'onset', 'staff', 'voice']
right_features = ['dynamics', 'chords']
join_on = [['mc', 'onset', 'staff', 'voice'], ['mc', 'onset', 'staff'], ['mc', 'onset']]
for on in join_on:
    match = right[on + right_features].merge(left[left_features], on=on, left_index=True)
    left_ix = match.index
    left.loc[left_ix, match.columns] = match
    # left.loc[left_ix].fillna(match, inplace=True)
    right_ix = right.merge(left[left_features], on=on, right_index=True).index
    right.drop(right_ix, inplace=True)
    if len(right) == 0:
        break
if len(right) > 0:
    print("WARNING: These events could not be attached:")
    print(right)
```

This approach does not work because after the first merge, `match` looks like this:

```
     mc onset  staff  voice dynamics chords  tpc
0 2   0     0      1      1        f    NaN    0
  3   0     0      1      1        f    NaN    4
  4   0     0      1      1        f    NaN    1
  5   0     0      1      1        f    NaN    0
  2   0     0      1      1      NaN      I    0
  3   0     0      1      1      NaN      I    4
  4   0     0      1      1      NaN      I    1
  5   0     0      1      1      NaN      I    0
  7   0   3/4      2      1      NaN    I64    1
```

Since the index of `match` is not unique, the assignment `left = match` is not fully working (`dynamics` are missing in the result) and the commented out approach with `fillna` silently doesn't do anything. Also, it bothers me to do the same merge twice in order to get the `left_index` for correct assignment and then the `right_index` for dropping the matched rows.

## Attempt 2

Facing these problems, I preprocess `right` before the join to unite simultaneous events in one row:

```
def unite_vals(df):
    r = pd.Series(index=right_features)
    for col in right_features:
        u = df[col][df[col].notna()].unique()
        if len(u) > 1:
            r[col] = ''.join(str(val) for val in u)
            print(f"WARNING:Two simultaneous events in row {df.iloc[0].name}")
        elif len(u) == 1:
            r[col] = u[0]
    return r

left_features = ['mc', 'onset', 'staff', 'voice']
right_features = ['dynamics', 'chords']
on = ['mc', 'onset']
right = right.groupby(on).apply(unite_vals).reset_index()
match = right.merge(left[left_features], on=on, left_index=True)
left_ix = match.index
left.loc[left_ix, match.columns] = match
# left.loc[left_ix].fillna(match, inplace=True)
right_ix = right.merge(left[left_features], on=on, right_index=True).index
right.drop(right_ix, inplace=True)
if len(right) > 0:
    print("WARNING: These events could not be attached:")
    print(right)
```

(For some unknown reason, the commented out approach with `fillna` again doesn't do anything. The issue of doing the same merge twice remains.) The result is one I could live with, however, it does not differentiate between the layers of `right` and therefore looks like this:

```
     mc onset  staff  voice  tpc dynamics chords
0 0   0     0      2      1    0        f      I
  1   0     0      2      1    0        f      I
  2   0     0      1      1    0        f      I
  3   0     0      1      1    4        f      I
  4   0     0      1      1    1        f      I
  5   0     0      1      1    0        f      I
  6   0   3/4      2      2    1      NaN  I6I64
  7   0   3/4      2      1    1      NaN  I6I64
WARNING:Two simultaneous events at:
   mc onset
3   0   3/4
WARNING: These events could not be attached:
   mc onset dynamics chords
1   0   1/2        p    NaN
```

How would this typically be solved?

Here is the source code for reproduction:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from fractions import Fraction
left_dict = {'mc': {(0, 0): 0,
  (0, 1): 0,
  (0, 2): 0,
  (0, 3): 0,
  (0, 4): 0,
  (0, 5): 0,
  (0, 6): 0,
  (0, 7): 0},
 'onset': {(0, 0): Fraction(0, 1),
  (0, 1): Fraction(0, 1),
  (0, 2): Fraction(0, 1),
  (0, 3): Fraction(0, 1),
  (0, 4): Fraction(0, 1),
  (0, 5): Fraction(0, 1),
  (0, 6): Fraction(3, 4),
  (0, 7): Fraction(3, 4)},
 'staff': {(0, 0): 2,
  (0, 1): 2,
  (0, 2): 1,
  (0, 3): 1,
  (0, 4): 1,
  (0, 5): 1,
  (0, 6): 2,
  (0, 7): 2},
 'voice': {(0, 0): 1,
  (0, 1): 1,
  (0, 2): 1,
  (0, 3): 1,
  (0, 4): 1,
  (0, 5): 1,
  (0, 6): 2,
  (0, 7): 1},
 'tpc': {(0, 0): 0,
  (0, 1): 0,
  (0, 2): 0,
  (0, 3): 4,
  (0, 4): 1,
  (0, 5): 0,
  (0, 6): 1,
  (0, 7): 1},
 'dynamics': {(0, 0): np.nan,
  (0, 1): np.nan,
  (0, 2): np.nan,
  (0, 3): np.nan,
  (0, 4): np.nan,
  (0, 5): np.nan,
  (0, 6): np.nan,
  (0, 7): np.nan},
 'chords': {(0, 0): np.nan,
  (0, 1): np.nan,
  (0, 2): np.nan,
  (0, 3): np.nan,
  (0, 4): np.nan,
  (0, 5): np.nan,
  (0, 6): np.nan,
  (0, 7): np.nan}}
left = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(left_dict)

right_dict = {'mc': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0},
 'onset': {0: Fraction(0, 1),
  1: Fraction(0, 1),
  2: Fraction(1, 2),
  3: Fraction(3, 4),
  4: Fraction(3, 4)},
 'staff': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 2},
 'voice': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1},
 'dynamics': {0: 'f', 1: np.nan, 2: 'p', 3: np.nan, 4: np.nan},
 'chords': {0: np.nan, 1: 'I', 2: np.nan, 3: 'I6', 4: 'I64'}}
right = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(right_dict)

attempt1 = True
if attempt1:
    left_features = ['mc', 'onset', 'staff', 'voice', 'tpc']
    right_features = ['dynamics', 'chords']
    join_on = [['mc', 'onset', 'staff', 'voice'], ['mc', 'onset', 'staff'], ['mc', 'onset']]
    for on in join_on:
        match = right[on + right_features].merge(left[left_features], on=on, left_index=True)
        left_ix = match.index
        left.loc[left_ix, match.columns] = match
        #left.loc[left_ix].fillna(match, inplace=True)
        right_ix = right.merge(left[left_features], on=on, right_index=True).index
        right.drop(right_ix, inplace=True)
        if len(right) == 0:
            break
    if len(right) > 0:
        print("WARNING: These events could not be attached:")
        print(right)
    print(left)
else:
    def unite_vals(df):
        r = pd.Series(index=right_features)
        for col in right_features:
            u = df[col][df[col].notna()].unique()
            if len(u) > 1:
                r[col] = ''.join(str(val) for val in u)
                print("WARNING:Two simultaneous events at:")
                print(df.iloc[:1][['mc', 'onset']])
            elif len(u) == 1:
                r[col] = u[0]
        return r

    left_features = ['mc', 'onset', 'staff', 'voice']
    right_features = ['dynamics', 'chords']
    on = ['mc', 'onset']
    right = right.groupby(on).apply(unite_vals).reset_index()
    match = right.merge(left[left_features], on=on, left_index=True)
    left_ix = match.index
    left.loc[left_ix, match.columns] = match
    # left.loc[left_ix].fillna(match, inplace=True)
    right_ix = right.merge(left[left_features], on=on, right_index=True).index
    right.drop(right_ix, inplace=True)
    if len(right) > 0:
        print("WARNING: These events could not be attached:")
        print(right)
    print(left)
```

Comment: Could you share your data in a format that is easy to use? `to_dict()` is nice, for example, since the result can just be fed into `from_dict()`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for looking in! Other than what I've included at the end of the post, what else do you want me to add?

Comment: No idea yet, first I have to actually dig into what seems like it’s going to be a difficult question ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all it has turned out that the easiest way to solve my problem is using loops:

```
isnan = lambda num:  num != num
right_features = ['dynamics', 'chords']
for i, r in right.iterrows():
    same_os = left.loc[(left.mc == r.mc) & (left.onset == r.onset)]
    if len(same_os) > 0:
        same_staff = same_os.loc[same_os.staff == r.staff]
        same_voice = same_staff.loc[same_staff.voice == r.voice]
        if len(same_voice) > 0:
            fill = same_voice
        elif len(same_staff) > 0:
            fill = same_staff
        else:
            fill = same_os

        for f in right_features:
            if not isnan(r[f]):
                F = left.loc[fill.index, f]
                notna = F.notna()
                if notna.any():
                    print(f"WARNING:Feature existed and was concatenated: {F[notna]}")
                    left.loc[F[notna].index, f] += r[f]
                    left.loc[F[~notna].index, f] = r[f]
                else:
                    left.loc[fill.index, f] = r[f]
    else:
        print(f"WARNING:Event could not be attached: {r}")
```